# Vertical-align doesn't work (with table-cell display)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/5qLDz/ inside which I want to have images vertically aligned to bottom of the container (with some padding from container itself). It doesn't work even with `li` having `display: table-cell` and both `li` and `img` having `vertical-align:bottom` set. What can it be?

Please stop posting solutions using `position: absolute`. As you can see in my code, I used `text-align: center` which is important there.

Comment: Please don't be rude to the responders. If 4 people supply the 'wrong' answer it's because you asked the 'wrong' question. We're not psychics, and we don't have crystal balls. Describe your problem accurately and you will get accurate answers. Also, you're suffering from ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're focusing on possible solution Y instead of on solving problem X that started it. `display:table-cell` is not going to help you here, it'll just make things messier.

Answer (score 3):

One simple fix is to set the line-height to be the same as the container height:

```
ul.thumbnails li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    height: 222px;
    line-height: 222px;
    display: table-cell;
}
ul.thumbnails li img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 22px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

That seems to work, http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5qLDz/20/

You only need to declare `vertical-align: bottom` on the `img` rule.

However, if you add other elements like captions or social media links this could affect how you implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of god don't use `display:table-cell` just to vertically align something. Just using relative positioning will also do this far more easily: [forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLCVT/).

Only changed the parent to `position:relative` and the child to `position:absolute`.

Comment: Your solution doesn't respect `text-align: center`. Images may have different sizes both horizontally and vertically, so I can't position them with `position: absolute`, I need something flexible.

Comment: If you want a solution to meet certain requirements, be sure to actually specify them.

Comment: If I used `text-align: center` it is pretty obvious that I need it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS:

```
div.left section.box ul.thumbnails {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.thumbnails li {

  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  height: 222px;
  position:relative;    
}
ul.thumbnails li img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 22px;
  position:absolute;
}
```